# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.TextView.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, if, firebase-database

Вопрос такой , короче мне нужно сделать так чтобы в списке фотография показывала наличие ссылки в базе.Делаю я таким образом , получаю данные с базы и проверяю через :

```
public void setDetails(Context applicationContext, String songName, String songSinger, String getkzSongytblink, String kzSongAuthorName, String getkzSongComposerName, String songText){
    //Views
    TextView mSongName = mView.findViewById(R.id.SongName);
    TextView mSingerName = mView.findViewById(R.id.SongSinger);
    ImageView mImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


   if(link.length()>1){
        mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_line_logo);
    }

    //Set data to views
    mSongName.setText(songName);
    mSingerName.setText(songSinger);
    link.setText(getkzSongytblink);
}
```

Но у меня выскакивает ошибка после запуска приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переменная `link` скорее всего не инициализирована.

Comment: link либо не определена, либо ссылается на несуществующий объект

Comment: давайте я ссылку скину на гитхаб https://github.com/Icorp/AnderKz

Comment: я прописал еще вот такую вещь link = mView.findViewById(R.id.textView); , теперь он показывает то что везде есть наличие ссылки , хотя их нету;

Comment: Что такое TextView link? объект который находится за пределами RecyclerView? тогда его нужно передавать а адаптер. Если это элемент списка - тогда его нужно инициализировать в адаптере, и присвоить данные для каждого элемента списка.

Comment: у вас просто нет TextView в разметке))) просто проверяет не View а Data те наличие у модели данных от этого показывайте иконку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setDeatails(...){

    //Views
    TextView mSongName = mView.findViewById(R.id.SongName);
    TextView mSingerName = mView.findViewById(R.id.SongSinger);
    ImageView mImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getkzSongytblink)) mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_line_logo);
    else  mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_line_logo);

    //Set data to views
    mSongName.setText(songName);
    mSingerName.setText(songSinger);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]